# FB.ui send variable returned in response variable in callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK FB.ui.  Can I pass a parameter with FB.ui so that it is returned with the response object?

My current attempt:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'stream.publish',
    message: message,
    display: 'popup', // force popup mode
    data: "shared_item_id=96"
    },    
function(response) {
    alert('Post was published.' + response.share_item_id);
});
```

Is there away to get that shared_item_id into the response object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can resolve it by using **closures**:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'stream.publish',
    message: message,
    display: 'popup' // force popup mode
    },    
(function(shared_item_id) {
    return function(response) {
        /* callback body */
        //share_item_id = 96
        alert('Post was published.' + shared_item_id);
    }
})(96/*value you want to have in callback*/)


);
```

Comment: fyi share_item_id should be shared_item_id.  It is obviously just a typo.  Thanks for the great answer.